# Dismiss Root Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm developing an application, and at some point I need a Modal ViewController to "become" the Root ViewController.

How can I dismiss the current rootController, and set my Modal as my new rootController?

Comment: please share the related code-base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set your root view controller nil.

```
  [self.window setRootViewController:nil];
   UIStoryboard *MainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"                                                             bundle: nil];
   Nearbylocations *introViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"near"];
   self.window.rootViewController=introViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code..

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:modalviewref];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope it helps you..!